# Remote debug broken with Android Chrome 89

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I want to inspect a page listed on chrome://inspect page on a remote Pixel 4 with OS version 11, I get a white page with just 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' shown.

I uninstalled all updates from Android Chrome, went down to version 83, and remote debugging started working again.

I have the same problem with current versions of Chrome beta/dev/canary.

Is this only a problem on my device, or a general problem? Any way to get remote debugging working with Chrome 89?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't get it working on Chrome 89 for now because this is a general problem. I got the same issue on Vivaldi 3.7 which runs Chromium 89. The only option for now is rolling back to previous working release.